# Laravel 4: users authentication (static)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I depend on API to validate username and password to login users,

how to authenticate user login without check Laravel DB? (like static)

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

the problem is Auth::attempt automatic check Laravel DB,

I need to validate it like this:

```
if($email == $input_email && $password == $input_password)
{
  //login
}
```

Comment: Well how else do you expect to actually check the username and password if you dont look at the database?

Comment: I will validate username and password using API (let we say I just have correct username and password in variables)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the username/password is correct via the API - [you can manually log in a user](http://laravel.com/docs/security#manually):

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
Auth::login($user);
```

This way you dont need to supply the username/password - Laravel will just log the user in for you.

Edit: if you dont have a user table - I think something like this would work

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = $email;
Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: what is the use of User::find(1);  why pass "1" ?

Comment: Well you change "1" to the ID of whatever user you want to login

Comment: so I can pass (email, user_id, ...) to User::where() to store it in cookies ?

Comment: no - the User::where() is just selecting the *right* user to be logged in. Once they are logged in, you just add cookies like normal.

Comment: I don't want to check Laravel DB at all,
 in fact I don't have DB for Laravel in my APP

Comment: ok - I've editted my answer again. You can create a user Model, which then allows you to create user objects to login.

Comment: this login users just fine, but didn't keep them login (just for current page), when try to pass remember parameter Auth::login($user, $remember = true) receive error (Laravel try to connect to DB)

Comment: The remember token is not required per page, that is for 'long' remembering (like weeks). It sounds like you have a seperate issue with 'sessions' not being remembered. You'll have to look into that as a seperate issue. There are a few posts on SO about Laravel and Sessions.

Comment: I think I should store username and other data in cookies normally away from Laravel login